# Comparing Multi-indexed Dataframes with Multiple Comparison Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have two sets of data in form of two DataFrames, `df1` and `df2`, which I want to compare with each other. Each DataFrame contains multiple entries with the hierarchical structure `Lang-Code`  `Node_Type`  `Node_ID`  `Entry_Type`, each entry consists out of two values, `Attribute A` and `Attribute B`.

I've multi-indexed the DataFrames according the hierarchical structure:

DataFrame `df1`:

```py
                                        Attribute A  Attribute B
Lang-Code Node_Type Node_ID Entry_Type                          
de        N1        918     A                     2         True
en        N1        421     A                     8         True
                    442     A                     3        False
                            A                     1        False
                            B                     5        False
          N2        732     A                     9        False
fr        N1        978     D                     2         True
```

DataFrame `df2`:

```py
                                        Attribute A  Attribute B
Lang-Code Node_Type Node_ID Entry_Type                          
de        N1        479     A                    92         True # Different value for Attribute A in df1
en        N1        734     A                     8         True
                            B                     1        False # Entry not conained in df1
                    887     A                     3        False
                            A                     1        False
                            B                     5        False
          N2        888     A                     9        False
fr        N4        264     D                     2         True # Different Node_Type in df1
```

I would be interested in which Nodes are identically regarding their contained values. However, while the `Node_Type` **must** match, `Node_ID` is an unique value used for grouping only (the actual value for `Node_ID` won't match, but both the number of entries as well as their values shall be considered).

In the example above, only certain nodes do match between `df1` and `df2`, so the result I try to achieve would be as follows:

```py
                                Attribute A  Attribute B
Lang-Code Node_Type Entry_Type                          
en        N1        A                     3        False
                    A                     1        False
                    B                     5        False
          N2        A                     9        False
```

I already tried looping through the dataframe with `df1.iterrows()` and `df.itertuples()` or using `df.merge()`, but especially the fact that the unique `Node_ID` fulfills a grouping purpose gives me a headache!

I am fairly new to working with pandas, so I am not fully familiar with every aspect yet, so any tips on how to perform such a comparison more efficiently would be very welcome! :)
Would it be e.g. more useful to transpose the DataFrame, to have `Attribute A` and `Attribute B` as an index?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't really bother about Node_ID in your output.
In that case you could first `droplevel(level='Node_ID')` and then `reset_index()` on both dataframes.
And then just do an inner merge on both dataframes and then you can set the index back using `set_index(['Lang_Code', 'Node_Type', 'Entry_Type'])`

so something like (not tested):

```
df1 = df1.droplevel(level=['Node_ID'])
df2 = df2.droplevel(level=['Node_ID'])
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=df1.columns.tolist(),how='inner')
df3.set_index(['Lang_Code','Node_Type', 'Entry_Type'], inplace=True)
```